# Pecl error when installing php71 on Centos6.9 by yum, remi repo

Tags: linux, php, pecl

I got package related error like this.

Error: Package: php-pecl-xhprof-0.9.4-4.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64

I guess it is related with dependency about pecl though... can't figure out.

I use to use php56 for a long time.

Does anyone help me ??

These are the error message.

```
$ sudo yum install --enablerepo=remi,remi-php71 php
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php.x86_64 0:7.1.20-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.20-1.el6.remi for package: php-7.1.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli(x86-64) = 7.1.20-1.el6.remi for package: php-7.1.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.36-1.el6.remi for package: php-devel-5.6.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:7.1.20-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20131106-64 for package: php-pecl-xdebug-2.4.1-1.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20131106-64 for package: php-pecl-zip-1.13.5-1.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20131106-64 for package: php-pecl-xhprof-0.9.4-4.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20131106-64 for package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-1.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64 for package: php-pecl-xdebug-2.4.1-1.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64 for package: php-pecl-zip-1.13.5-1.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64 for package: php-pecl-xhprof-0.9.4-4.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64 for package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-1.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.36-1.el6.remi for package: php-xml-5.6.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.36-1.el6.remi for package: php-mbstring-5.6.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.36-1.el6.remi for package: php-intl-5.6.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.36-1.el6.remi for package: php-bcmath-5.6.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.36-1.el6.remi for package: php-opcache-5.6.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.36-1.el6.remi for package: php-pdo-5.6.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.36-1.el6.remi for package: php-process-5.6.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.36-1.el6.remi for package: php-mcrypt-5.6.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.36-1.el6.remi for package: php-soap-5.6.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:7.1.20-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php-bcmath.x86_64 0:7.1.20-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20131106-64 for package: php-pecl-xhprof-0.9.4-4.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64 for package: php-pecl-xhprof-0.9.4-4.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:7.1.20-1.el6.remi will be obsoleting
---> Package php-intl.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php-intl.x86_64 0:7.1.20-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-json.x86_64 0:7.1.20-1.el6.remi will be obsoleting
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:7.1.20-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:7.1.20-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-opcache.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php-opcache.x86_64 0:7.1.20-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.36-1.el6.remi for package: php-mysqlnd-5.6.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:7.1.20-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.10-1.el6.remi.5.6 will be obsoleted
---> Package php-pecl-jsonc-devel.x86_64 0:1.3.10-1.el6.remi.5.6 will be obsoleted
---> Package php-pecl-xdebug.x86_64 0:2.4.1-1.el6.remi.5.6 will be updated
---> Package php-pecl-xdebug.x86_64 0:2.6.1-1.el6.remi.7.1 will be an update
---> Package php-pecl-zip.x86_64 0:1.13.5-1.el6.remi.5.6 will be updated
---> Package php-pecl-zip.x86_64 0:1.15.3-1.el6.remi.7.1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libzip5(x86-64) >= 1.5.1 for package: php-pecl-zip-1.15.3-1.el6.remi.7.1.x86_64
---> Package php-process.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php-process.x86_64 0:7.1.20-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-soap.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php-soap.x86_64 0:7.1.20-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:7.1.20-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libzip5.x86_64 0:1.2.0-1.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package libzip5.x86_64 0:1.5.1-1.el6.remi will be an update
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20131106-64 for package: php-pecl-xhprof-0.9.4-4.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64 for package: php-pecl-xhprof-0.9.4-4.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64
---> Package php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.6.36-1.el6.remi will be updated
---> Package php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:7.1.20-1.el6.remi will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-pecl-xhprof-0.9.4-4.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
           Requires: php(api) = 20131106-64
           Removing: php-common-5.6.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
               php(api) = 20131106-64
           Updated By: php-common-7.1.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
               php(api) = 20160303-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-14.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-7.1.19-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
               php(api) = 20160303-64
Error: Package: php-pecl-xhprof-0.9.4-4.el6.remi.5.6.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Removing: php-common-5.6.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Updated By: php-common-7.1.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
               php(zend-abi) = 20160303-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-13.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-14.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-7.1.19-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
               php(zend-abi) = 20160303-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0):

**[xhprof](https://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof)** is not compatible with PHP 7.x (dead project), so yum prevent you from upgrading (by design)

If can remove this extension, you will be able to upgrade

```
yum remove php-pecl-xhprof
```

If you really need it, you have to stay with PHP 5.x

See the [compatibility list](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/PECL-extensions-RPM-status).